# How to know the plane size in units?

Tags: c++, opengl

Well the thing is, that I wan't to picture mazes with a different width and height. I'm drawing them in units and my question is, how can I get the plane viewable dimensions in units that I would know how deep inside the screen I would have to draw my maze in order it would be fully seeable. For perspective view I use "::gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 100.0f);"

[image: perspective]

For example how I get the near plane dimensions(width and height) in OpenGL units or the far plane or any plane between those planes. If I want to picture something entirely seeable I need to know the plane dimensions in OpenGL units or is there another way?

Comment: Please attach a picture illustrating your situation. It's hard to answer the question without seeing more detail.

Comment: Is "plaine" a typo for "plane", or is it some technical term I haven't encountered before?

Comment: In Germany we would call it "Dreisatz".

Comment: Sorry, yes the correct word is plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of trigonometry will tell you that: `h_near = 2*near*tan(fovy/2)` and the same for far: `h_far = 2*far*tan(fovy/2)`

Then, the ratio will give you the width.

For the "proof", just consider the right-angled triangle formed by the line of view, the vertical of the plane of rendering and back. The length of the line of view is `near` or `far` (depending), the angle at the eye position is `fovy/2` (i.e. half the view angle) and the vertical on the plane is `h_near/2` or `h_far/2`, as we only get half-way to the plane. Then, the tangent of the angle on a right-angled triangle is equal to the far-side divided by the near-side ...