# OpenGL Convert ClipCoord to ScreenCoord

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I want to convert ClipCoord to ScreenCoord but I don't know what is the right way to get the Canvas width and height.
(Canvas = the drawable area in the image plane)

```
glm::vec4 clipCoords = vec4f(0.1f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f) // random point

float canvasWidth = 2;
float canvasHeight = 2;

GLfloat ndcX = (clipCoords.x + canvasWidth / 2.0f) / canvasWidth;
GLfloat ndcY = (clipCoords.y + canvasHeight / 2.0f) / canvasHeight;

GLint pixelX = ndcX * SCREEN_WIDTH;
GLint pixelY = (1 - ndcY) * SCREEN_HEIGHT;
```

In OpenGL, the canvas is the nearPlane in the perspective projection.

[I found old thread with same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171590/how-to-know-the-plane-size-in-units)

so I have the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a function that takes a point glm::vec2 ( convert it to `glm::vec2` by using the `matrix multiplication` from the camera matrix ) and then get it to Screen by value mapping.

A helpful link might be [this](https://community.khronos.org/t/converting-object-to-screen-coordinates/65317)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you are using for creating the window with the OpenGL Context. E.g. if you use GLFW (a great library for window creation btw), you get the the framebuffer size with `glfwGetFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int* width, int* height)`, like so:

```
int width;
int height;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
```

But this is only the framebuffer size, if you want to get the viewport, which is how many pixel will be written from OpenGL into the framebuffer, `glGetIntegerv(GLenum pname, GLint* data` is what you are looking for:

```
GLint* viewport = new GLint[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
int x =      viewport[0];
int y =      viewport[1];
int width =  viewport[2];
int height = viewport[3];
delete[] viewport;
```